# StaticInjectorError Spec Angular Test

Tags: angular, angular-test

Usually, I get the following error if I haven't included a dependency in my Testbed which is required by the constructor of the class I'm testing. But in this case, the missing dependency is the class I'm testing.

## Error

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[AuthGuardService]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthGuardService!
```

## Question:

What do I need to add in order to get the test passed?

### AuthGuardService Spec

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AuthGuardService} from './auth-guard.service';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('AuthGuardService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const userServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['isAuthenticated']);
    const routerServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('RouterService', ['navigate']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: UserService, useValue: userServiceSpy},
        {provide: Router, useValue: routerServiceSpy}
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: AuthGuardService = TestBed.get(AuthGuardService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

### AuthGuardService

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) {
  }

  async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const authStatus = await this.userService.isAuthenticated();
    if (authStatus === true) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['front'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: The AuthGuardService has no self provider. Try to provide the service in your TestBed.

Comment: Is this because it's not `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`? So I just need to add `providers: [AuthGuardService]` in the `Testbed`, right?

Comment: Ok, that worked thx.